# java exec with process replacement

Tags: java, multithreading, exec, fork

Here is command from python:
os.execvp
it runs other application and current process is completely replaced with new one. From script point of view, os.execvp never returns result.

The question is how to make the same in Java. E.g. - I have app1.class and run it. It must execute other application, but the process should be replaced.

Do you know how to make it in java?

thank you

Comment: I don't understand the process replaced part. What do you mean by that?

Comment: You can use [ProcessBuilder.start()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29) or [Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) to start a new [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). I am not 100% sure if this is what you were asking for

Comment: Waht @CoolBeans talks about ends up doing `fork()/execve()` on Unix. I think `fork()` can be `vfork()` or `posix_spawn()` on Java 1.7, for efficient implementation (it was always `fork()` on Java 1.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in only Java.  You have to spawn a new process and let the old one die.

It might be possible to create an JNI library on *nix and let it do exec for you. That
would only work on unix-like operating systems. On windows you would have to spawn a new
process and wait for it.